# if else in regex?

Tags: php, regex

My import file contains a column `params`. This column can contain a string of parameters separated by `|`, for example `name:value|name1:value1|name2:value2`. But sometimes this column may contain other parameters, for example `other_name|other_value`.

I need a regular expression that would remove everything from this column except `value2`. And if the column does not find `value2` at all, then return an empty row.

I'm trying something like this `(?(?=.*).*name2:)`, but it doesn't work if the row contains other data that needs to be deleted completely.

Comment: what is the language?

Comment: `(?=.*)` is useless, it means "anything can appear on the right".

Comment: That's the wrong way of thinking in regex. You want to *match "value2"* via some expression that is guaranteed to match only it, and if that column doesn't exist, then you'll get an empty match…

Comment: @deceze Yes, I only need to get value2, which corresponds to name2 and if name2 does not exist, then return an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_match('~\bname2:([^|]*)~', $text, $m)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QbJ9c1/3/). *Details*

- `\bname2` - a whole word `name2`
- `:` - a colon
- `([^|]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `|`.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/mq2Ma):

```php
$text = "name:value|name1:value1|name2:value2";
$result = "";
if (preg_match('~\bname2:([^|]*)~', $text, $m)) {
    $result = $m[1];
}
echo $result;
// => value2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either capture the part after `name2:` and use group 1 in the replacement, and if it is not there match the whole string to be removed.

```
.*\bname2:([^|\n]+).*|.+
```

- `.*\bname2:` Match till `name2:`
- `([^|\n]+)` Capture group 1, match 1 or more following chars other than `|` as that is the delimiter
- `.*` Optionally match the rest of the line
- `|` Or
- `.+` Match 1 or more characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m7RCAg/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/2R0Qi)

```
$re = '/.*\bname2:([^|\n]+).*|.+/';
$str = 'name:value|name1:value1|name2:value2
name:value|name1:value1|name2:value2|name:value
other_name|other_value';

$result = preg_replace($re, '$1', $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
value2
value2
```